# Help to understand the claim with the stereographic projection

Tags: general-topology, stereographic-projections

I don't understand the following claim: We consider $\Bbb S^2$ as a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$. We have the stereographic projection $\rho: \Bbb S^2 \setminus \{(0,0,1)\} \to \Bbb R^2$, $\rho (x,y,z)=\frac{(x,y)}{1-z}$. Now $\rho$ is a homeomorphismus. Now they claim is that the set $\Bbb S^2 \setminus \{(0,0,1)\}$ is an open set (with the relativ topology??) containing all but one point on the sphere and so every point except for possibly $(0,0,1)$ has a euclidiean neighborhood. How they conclude this? Why is there a euclidean neighborhood? Can someone please helps me?

Comment: You should provide the context in which this occurs (a lecture, a book?). And who are "they"?

Answer (score 1):

The conecpt of a "Euclidean neighborhood" occurs in the context of *toplogical manifolds*. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold. Quote from the section "Coordinate charts":

> By definition, every point of a locally Euclidean space has a neighborhood homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$. Such neighborhoods are called **Euclidean neighborhoods**.

More generally, we may say that an open neigborhood of a point $x$ of a topological space $X$ is a Euclidean neighborhood if it is homeomorphic to an open subset of some $\mathbb R^n$.

In your example $U = S^2 \setminus \{(0,0,1)\}$ is an open subspace of $S^2$ which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$. Thus each $x \in S$ has a Euclidean neighborhood (namely $U$).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bijection, which projects every point of the sphere at some point at a plane. Additionally, a stereographic projection makes circles from circles.

So possibly they mean a topology of a plane, projected onto a sphere?

PS
Possibly, in $\rho: \Bbb S^2 \setminus \{0,0,1\} \to \Bbb R^2$ you should use $\{(0,0,1)\}$ instead of $ \{0,0,1\}$ ...?